# Convert json string to Java Map(JSONLib)

Tags: java, json, json-lib

How can I convert json string to Java Map using JSON-lib(http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) ?
I can convert to DynaBean:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( str );  
DynaBean bean = (DynaBean) JSONSerializer.toJava( jsonObject );
```

but I have not found a method to convert directly to Java Map

**Edit:**

I have found the solution:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( str );
Map<String, Object> myMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSONObject.toBean(jsonObject, Map.class)
```

Comment: Can you please post your solution as an answer to your own question and accept it? Cheers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Another approach is to take advantage of the fact that a `JSONObject` implements `java.util.Map`.  So, it *is* a map.

```
import java.util.Map;

import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

public class Foo
{
  static String json = "{\"one\":\"won\",\"two\":2,\"three\":false}";

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(json);
    Map map = jsonObject;
    System.out.println(map);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, haven't noticed this:) Thanks!

Comment: If there's any interest in further decoupling the resulting Map from JSON-lib, note that it's trivial to create a new Map from an existing Map's entries using a copy constructor, such as Map map = new HashMap(jsonObject);

Comment: What if the JSON is nested?

Comment: Please Note, this answer is not valid for org.json.JSONArray!