# Json to server error

Tags: android, json

I got this error...

```
10-27 12:07:08.101 10065-10108/com.example.sebastian.patientdetails D/TAG_NAME: [{"_id":"1","name":"Sss","dob":"10\/1\/2000","gender":"Male","mobile":"1234567890","address":"asdasd"}]
10-27 12:07:08.102 10065-10108/com.example.sebastian.patientdetails E/Volley: [141] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to java.util.Map
                                                                          java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to java.util.Map
                                                                              at com.example.sebastian.patientdetails.MainActivity$3$3.getParams(MainActivity.java:112)
                                                                              at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:460)
                                                                              at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:253)
                                                                              at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:227)
                                                                              at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:107)
                                                                              at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97)
                                                                              at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
```

I need to sent my json array to a server url. When i click the button i got this error. Can anyody suggest me whats the error means.? Can anybody suggest me a good tutorial for json to server inserting.?

MainActivity Code...

```
    ...
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddPatient.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            getResults();

            StringRequest request=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, server_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }){

            protected Map<String,String>getParams()throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> parameters= new HashMap<String, String>();
                    return (Map<String, String>) getResults();
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(request);
        }
    });
}

private JSONArray getResults() {

    String myPath = "/data/data/com.example.sebastian.patientdetails/databases/" + "MyDBName.db";

    String myTable = "patients";


    SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    String searchQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + myTable;
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(searchQuery, null);

    JSONArray resultSet = new JSONArray();

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

        int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
        JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();

        for (int i = 0; i < totalColumn; i++) {
            if (cursor.getColumnName(i) != null) {
                try {
                    if (cursor.getString(i) != null) {
                        Log.d("TAG_NAME", cursor.getString(i));
                        rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), cursor.getString(i));
                    } else {
                        rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), "");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("TAG_NAME", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        resultSet.put(rowObject);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    Log.d("TAG_NAME", resultSet.toString());
    return resultSet;
}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert JSONArray to Map , but you can convert JSONObject to Map and can get value by keys.
First get JSONObject from the JSONArray and convert it to Map.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot convert `JSONArray` cannot be cast to `java.util.Map`
you should found some solution on stack overflow related your error

Comment: And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323205/convert-json-string-to-java-mapjsonlib) you go ...

Answer (score 1):

[reference link please Visit this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544133/parsing-json-array-into-java-util-list-with-gson)

```
    import java.lang.reflect.Type;
    import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
    // ...
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
    List<String> yourList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonResponce, listType);
```